# dynamically change actionbar height

Tags: android, android-actionbar

On a certain activity, I need an actionbar height of 7 dip. I am setting this using:

```
<item name="android:actionBarSize">6dip</item>
```

however after a certain point I want to return the bar to it's normal height. how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so i have this problem for hours, i post the question, then i find the answer on my own after 10 minutes.

what you do is you have two themes in styles.xml:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">6dip</item>

    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@android:color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

my AndroidManifest.xml is:

```
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    ...
```

on the activity i want small actionbar i do:

```
    setTheme(R.style.SplashTheme);
```

Comment: That doesn't work perfectly, since the `setTheme` method needs to be called the `setContentView` method. I know we could `recreate` the activity, but sometimes we just can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to change the action bar size. 
1.using manifest file under given activity tag.

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme1"
```

2.programatically yo can use

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
setTheme(android.R.style.AppTheme1);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
}
```

afrer this set the hieght of Apptheme1